# how to create route for history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Index.html.slim

```
div class="container home"
  div class="row"
    div class="col"
      h1 = t '.main_header'
      h3 = link_to fa_icon('download'), admins_users_path(format: "csv")
      table class="table"
        thead
          tr
            td = t '.table.email_col'
            td = t '.table.last_visit_col'
            td = t '.table.view_info_col'
            td = t 'Edit'
            td = t 'History'

        - @users.each do |user|
          tr id="user-info-#{user.id}"
            td = user.email
            td = user.last_sign_in_at
            td = link_to fa_icon('eye'), admins_user_path(user.id)
            td = link_to fa_icon('edit'), edit_admins_user_path(user.id)
            td = link_to fa_icon('history'), admins_users_history_path(user.id)
```

UsersController

```
module Admins
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render404
    layout 'admin'
    before_action :find_user, except: [:index]
    def index
      @users = User.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv do
          send_data UsersCsvGenerator.call(@users,
                                           fields: %w[email last_sign_in_at])
        end
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      render 'edit'
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update(params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name,
                                                   :last_name, :password))
        redirect_to 'edit', notice: 'Successfully Updated'
      else
        @user.errors.full_messages
        render 'show'

      end
    end

    def history
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def render404
      render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false, status: 404
    end
  end
end
```

routes

```
  namespace :admins do
    resources :users, only: %i[index show edit update history]
    get '/users/history', to: 'users#history'
    resources :calculators, only: %i[new create edit update]
  end
```

history.html.slim

```
- @user.versions.reverse.each do |version|
  div class="container"
  table class="table"
    thead
      tr
  th =  version.id
  th = 'Changes'
  th = version.created_at
  th = version.event
  br
```

Hello
I have a problem, I don't how to create route for history for each user
When I wrote like here, in web my link looks like localhost:3000/admins/users/history.1
I need to be http://localhost:3000/admins/users/1/history

> get '/users/history', to: 'users#history'

Answer (score 0):

`:history` action should be a nested `get` route on `member` like below:

```
#=> config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admins do
    resources :users, only: %i[index show edit update history] do
      get :history, on: :member
    end
    resources :calculators, only: %i[new create edit update]
  end
end
```

Results in:

```
localhost:3000/admins/users/1/history
```

Ref: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes